# Update Error /boot/efi does not have sufficient space

Tags: drivers, updates

I was trying to update firmware but It wasn't installing any updates.On running  sudo fwupdmgr get-devices I found following error:
UpdateError:          /boot/efi does not have sufficient space, required 33.6 MB, got 8.5 MB

Comment: Did you solve this? I'm getting the same message after upgrading to 20.04.

Comment: yes, I think this arises due to bootloaders of different OS that , in my case was still there

Comment: For anyone coming to this, I managed to resolve a similar problem for mine: https://askubuntu.com/a/1266370/430577